# django image management

Tags: django, image

In my project I'am working with images. I don't know how to organize the management of images.

I need to dynamically upload the pictures and resize them.

First question - what is the best way to dynamically upload images with progress bar and without flash? I found [this](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/679/) and [this](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/678/), but I believe there is a better way.

Second question. I have to save one image in different sizes. I won't use these thumbnails on my pages, but another application will. Many clients could upload images at the same time. This means that I can not resize all the images at the same time. How should I organize this process?

Is there are a better ready-to-use solution for image management issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[django-photologue](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/) could be a good starting point for organizing the management of your images.

The [`PhotoSize`](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/wiki/PhotoSize) model can be used to automatically resize/crop your images, and the [`GalleryUpload`](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/wiki/GalleryUpload) model allows the user to upload an archive of images.

You can also create `PhotoSize` models with `pre_cache = False`. This means that your images will dynamically created the first time they are requested.

For your second question you might use a task queue, like [django-celery](http://celeryproject.org/docs/django-celery/) or [django-tasks](http://code.google.com/p/django-tasks/).

Comment: Tnx! but how django-photologue help me in situation when many clients upload images at same time? If I resize all images, the memory will end.

Comment: @Andrey You can create `PhotoSize` models with `pre_cache = False`. This means that your images will dynamically created the first time they are requested.

Comment: which way they should be requested? I won't request them on my pages. These thumbnails are needed for another application, not for my site. And what about memory? To resize the ten images at the same time may run out of memory

Answer (score 0):

For the image crop, try [Python Imaging Library (PIL)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)